# Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled portfolio sorting

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, regression, finance

I'm trying to sort  3 size portfolios and perform a 2-stage Fama Macbeth regression with excess portfolios returns on LHS and FF3 factors on RHS.

The issue is that I get an error message that "matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate" from the 2-stage regression.  I get this error if I use just some random numbers or my actual data, so my suspicion is that there an error in my way of sorting the portfolios.

I get the mistake in the last row of the code. Specifically, in the "XSReg".
Here is a link for the "XSReg": http://www.julianthimme.de/code

Can somebody perhaps see where I'm messing up with the portfolio sorting?

The code below uses just some random data

```
clear all 
clc
%% Setting up data
RET=[1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 2 2 2 2; 3 3 3 3;3.5 3.3 3.4 3.6];
MEQ=[100 150 200 300;100 150 200 300;100 150 200 300;100 150 200 300;10 150 250 100];
SMB=[10; 4; 4; 5;6];
HML=[2; 3; 4; -1;-2];
market_ret=[10; 4; 4; 5;6];
rf=[0.10; 0.4; 0.4; 0.5;0.6];
T=length(RET);
nAss=size(RET,2);


%%Calculating breakpoints
nPort=3; %Nr of portfolios
Breakpoint=NaN(T,nPort-1);
for i=1:T; %Setting the breakpoints
    Breakpoint(i,:)=  quantile(MEQ(i,:),nPort-1);
end


%%Assigning returns & market equity to matrixes based on breakpoints
h_meq=NaN(T,nAss);
m_meq=NaN(T,nAss);
l_meq=NaN(T,nAss);
h_ret=NaN(T,nAss);
m_ret=NaN(T,nAss);
l_ret=NaN(T,nAss);
for i=1:T;
    for k=1:nAss;
    if MEQ(i,k)>=Breakpoint(i,2);
       h_meq(i,k)=MEQ(i,k);
       h_ret(i,k)=RET(i,k);
    end
    if MEQ(i,k)<Breakpoint(i,2) & MEQ(i,k)>Breakpoint(i,1);
       m_meq(i,k)=MEQ(i,k);
       m_ret(i,k)=RET(i,k);
    end
    if MEQ(i,k)<=Breakpoint(i,1);
      l_meq(i,k)=MEQ(i,k);
      l_ret(i,k)=RET(i,k);
    end
end
end

%%Calculating the weighted return
for i=1:T
    for k=1:nAss;
        w_ret_h(i,k)=h_ret(i,k)*(h_meq(i,k)/nansum(h_meq(i,k)));
        w_ret_m(i,k)=m_ret(i,k)*(m_meq(i,k)/nansum(m_meq(i,k)));
        w_ret_l(i,k)=l_ret(i,k)*(l_meq(i,k)/nansum(l_meq(i,k)));
    end
end


%%Summing up to get portfolio returns
VWport=NaN(T,nPort);
for i=1:T
    VWport(i,1)=nansum(w_ret_l(i,:));
    VWport(i,2)=nansum(w_ret_m(i,:));
    VWport(i,3)=nansum(w_ret_h(i,:));
end
ExcessVWport=VWport-rf;

%%2stage Fama Macbeth regression
factors=[excessmkt SMB HML]; 
returns=ExcessVWport;
[lambda, tlambda, R2adj, RMSE, alpha, talpha, beta, tbeta, GRS, pval, vcv]=XSReg(returns, factors, 1, 1, [], 2, 'HACC_B');
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: I get the mistake in the last row of the code. Specifically, in the "XSReg". 

Here is a link for the XSReg function:
http://www.julianthimme.de/code?fbclid=IwAR3ZnDTl2HKYiXDCMb3b79COcXkK6XuCoFsoS_hiiZUM7Vgcc1xt7aDsrqU

Comment: Thanks; you should specify where you are getting an error **in your question's code, not in the comments.** It's a good practice to specify what piece of your code produces an error when asking a question about a bug.